Bevel works fine on one side, but not properly on the other side
I want to round the corners of this chair: 
But 2 corners are rounded incorrectly and i cant figure out why. Face orientation is correctly, there are no double edges, rotation and scale is applied. 
On the other side everything is fine: 
My Blend file:

I can't solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Hello could you please share your file?

Please share your Blend file which you can do via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it. Thanks.

Hi! I added my blend file. I'm using version 4.0 if that matters.

Looking at the internal geometry, it is not manifold. There are extra walls between the seat and frame, and the faces of each leg that are against the between-leg walls go across them.

I deleted the vertical edges, and the shorter horizontal ones, then recreated the leg sides to look more like this:

After that, I recalculated the normals outside just to be safe. Performing a bevel on all sharp edges with the outer miter type set to "arc" seems to give the desired result now:

